# Cycle through show-paren-style and highlight-sexp

Tags: highlighting

I have the following code, `rk-bracemk-companion` changes the
`show-paren-style` ("parenthesis", "expression", "mixed"), whereas
`rk-emph-symbolic-expressions` enables `highlight-sexp`.

After trying `highlight-sexp` with `show-paren-mode`, I have
encountered some conflicting behavior.  Might be a better idea
not to have them both enabled.

Was thinking of using a switch that changes through

`show-paren-style parenthesis`
`show-paren-style expression`
`show-paren-style mixed`
`highlight-sexp`

Which I could use a function to enable one over the others,
and use a keybinding to cycle through, calling it `rk-brace-syntac-sweep`.

But do not have a good idea how to write `rk-brace-syntac-sweep`.

```lisp
(defcustom rk-bracemk-companion-style
  '(parenthesis expression mixed)
  "Completion candidates for `rk-bracemk-companion'."
  :type '(repeat symbol)
  :group 'convenience)

(defun rk-bracemk-companion (style)
  "Choose a `show-paren-style' and use it.  
Indicates counterpart character when matching bracketing pairs."

  (interactive
   (list
    (completing-read "bracemk-companion, Style Completion: "
             richerenkov-bracemk-companion-style nil t)))

  (customize-set-variable 'show-paren-delay 1.3)

  ;; Options: Style | "parenthesis", "expression", "mixed"
  (customize-set-variable 'show-paren-style (intern style))
  (customize-set-variable 'show-paren-when-point-inside-paren t)

  (show-paren-mode -1)
  (show-paren-mode 1))

(defun rk-emph-symbolic-expressions ()
  "Emphasises symbolic expressions."

  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/Opstk/bin/contrib/emph-sexp")

  (require 'highlight-sexp)
 
  (setq hl-sexp-background-color "#221044") 
  (add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook 'highlight-sexp-mode)
  (add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'highlight-sexp-mode))

(defun rk-brace-syntac-sweep ()
  "Emphasises symbolic expressions."
    (rk-bracemk-companion "expression")
    (rk-emph-symbolic-expressions)
  )
```

Comment: What's the question? Is it *"How can I write rk-brace-syntac-sweep?"* That's too broad. Please take such questions to a discussion site, such as Reddit.

Comment: I want to successively enable a specific customisation (e.g. show parenthesis only) with the others switched off.  With a keybinding I would more through the separate customisations.  But I have to switch off the other customisations as I cycle through.